Pine script. Получить цену актива за предыдущие 60 секунд
Подскажите, как получить цену актива, допустим, за предыдущие 60 секунд, чтобы сравнить её с текущей?
На 1 сек графике, некоторые свечи (бары) из-за низкой ликвидности объединяются в большие помежутки (15 сек). И получается, если бы все свечи присутствовали, то можно было запросто использовать close[59], но из-за некоторых объединнённых свечей это может быть цена за предыдущие 3 мин и 5 мин.

request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', close[1])

